# Check if List has been changed

Tags: java, android, firebase

I was wondering how I could **check** if my `List`, has been changed? The coder down under, is being run every 5 sec, and if new data is implemented in the database it will be in the `List`.

```java
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
        String Group_Names = document.getString("Title");
        System.out.println("Groups: Listen to these - " + document.getString("Title"));
        list.add(Group_Names);
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Failed on: " + task.getException());
}
```

Comment: [`javafx.collections.ObservableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use List's `hashCode()` to check if the list was modified or not

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            int oldhashCode = list.hashCode();
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                String Group_Names = document.getString("Title");
                System.out.println("Groups: Listen to these - " + document.getString("Title"));
                list.add(Group_Names);
            }
            int newhashCode = list.hashCode();
if(oldhashCode == newhashCode) {  // hashcode is unique for very object in Java and fastest way to compare two object of same type
                System.out.println("List is unchanged");
            } else {
                System.out.println("List is\changed");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed on: " + task.getException());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use live data and observer the list change. Wherever you are updating or the item is getting added into the list, let the observer know that the item is updated and observe the result.

As an example :

```
MutableLiveData<Boolean> isMyListUpdatedLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
        String Group_Names = document.getString("Title");
        System.out.println("Groups: Listen to these - " + document.getString("Title"));
        list.add(Group_Names);
isMyListUpdatedLiveData.post(true);
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Failed on: " + task.getException());
}


public LiveData<Boolean> getListUpdates() {
return isMyListUpdatedLiveData;
}
```

Now wherever you want to observe the results, just call this :

```
getListUpdates().observe(this, boolean -> {

            // do whatever you want here when list is updated
        });
```